# Here Api - List all cities of State

Tags: here-api

How can I list all cities by state using Here API?

For example:

Request: country=BRA and state=SC

Response: city1, city2, city3...

I have tried without sucess:

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json
 ?level=city&mode=retrieveAreas
 &app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}
 &country=BRA&state=SC
 &additionaldata=city,true; street,false; district, false; state,false; country, false
```

But it returns me only the corresponding state

Answer (score 0):

The Geocoder is here not the right service for your approach. You need to consider that it is designed for geocoding addresses and not doing a look-up search in that dimension.

What I would recommend here is to check the API for Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets:

See further details here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/what-is.html

Comment: As of May 2022 the link provided to the recommended API is no longer working.